# Implement alpha beta prunning for multiplayer minimax

Tags: java, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning, game-theory

I successfully implemented the minimax algorithm for a game that I have coded.

The problem is the amount of possible moves. Sorting some of those out will not work because everyone of those moves might make sense.

My implementation is the following:

```
public int[] max (int depth, int player) {
    HashSet<Vector3i> vector3is = possibleMoves();          //Vector3i is equal to a move
    if(depth == 0 || vector3is.size() == 0){
        int[] ret = gameMap.getEvaluation();
        return ret;
    }

    int[] val = new int[players];
    int diff = -10000000;
    for(Vector3i v:vector3is){
        gameMap.place((int)v.x,(int)v.y,(int)v.z, player);  //takes the move
        int nextID = (player + 1) % players;                //nextPlayer ID
        int[] ar = max(depth-1, nextID);

        int diffN = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if(i == player){
                diffN += ar[i];
            }else{
                diffN -= (int)(1.1 * ar[i]);
            }
        }

        if(diffN >= diff) {
            if(depth == this.depth)  {
                move = v;
            }
            diff = diffN;
            val = ar;
        }
        gameMap.undoPlace();
    }
    return val;
}
```

`gameMap.getEvaluation()` does not include minimizing the value of other players.
Therefor, in the forloop, my code tries to maximize the value `diffN` which takes into account the positioning of the other players at that given state.
The evaluation is given as an int[]. index 0 is the positioning for player with index 0 etc.

Now, I'd like to implement alphabeta-prunning with this. I assume that, instead of 2 values, alpha and beta, I need an array with the size, equal to the amount of players I got.

I just do not know how to implement that.

I would be very happy if someone could help me with that.

Greetings, Finn

Comment: So you have n player minimax, and your number of moves is too great? So you want α-β pruning to reduce them? I would start with limiting depth first so that it finishes in a reasonable amount of time. Then, add α-β pruning to compare runtimes for the same depth. Otherwise, yes, you need pruning values for each player.

Comment: Well I got a depth of 3 and I cannot go any lower because that would lead to a logic problem in my game.

Comment: I've got up to 200 moves each depth

Comment: Whoa, ok. So you have some serious branching. You're going to need lots of tricks for minimax to work. Are there any quick ways to evaluate (estimate) a certain board/game state without playing subsequent moves? Also consider [Monte Carlo search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search).

Comment: So what I am doing is playing 5 wins in 3D.
The evaluation goes kinda quick: row of 2: 10p row of 3: 100p row of 4:1000p, row of 5: 10000p. You only get points for a row that could be finished to 5 stones. 

My possible moves is equal to every empty place that is next to a placed stone.

Comment: what exactly is the benefit of monte carlo searche?

Comment: To rank moves based on how often they lead to successful end-games.